# Painting a backpack

Tags: painting

I'm planning to paint something on my 'Naugahyde leather' backpack. What type of paint should I use for that? I have already tried it with fabric paint, but it got smudged after a couple of days.

Comment: What's the backpack made of? What specific type of paint did you use? How did you use it? As this question stands currently, it's too vague to answer.

Comment: Painting in cordura or a vinyl is going to need a different paint than cotton canvas.

Comment: Besides the material, like nylon vs. cotton, which are completely different for painting, a natural fabric like cotton may have some form of waterproofing, which would really introduce a problem for painting.  If the backpack doesn't have a label identifying the material, can you guess at it?

Comment: Thanks for adding the information on the material.  In your comment, you refer to it as a "leather material".  It would make a big difference whether it is real leather or Naugahyde (the surface of which is vinyl).  Can you add that clarification?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I edited the question as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fabric paint** or **acrylic paint** are probably still your best options for painting a backpack. However, you may want to consider a better quality brand of paint if it smudges right off after drying.

Some other things you might want to consider are:

- Wash the fabric first before painting, if possible. Sometimes they're treated to be stain-resistant, which would make it more difficult for paints to stick.
- If you're using acrylic paint, you may want to mix it with a binder medium to help it "stick" better to the fabric. (Example: https://canarystreetcrafts.com/how-to-turn-any-acrylic-paint-into-fabric-paint/)
- Another option would be to paint on canvas (like the material used for canvas tote bags), and then sew the canvas onto the backpack. (Example: https://www.artistshelpingchildren.org/kidscraftsactivitiesblog/2009/08/how-to-personalize-your-school-bags-draw-on-and-paint-your-backpacks/)
- You may consider applying gesso first to help prevent the fabric from absorbing so much paint that it doesn't show up. (See here for details: https://www.instructables.com/id/Painted-Garden-Backpack/)
- After painting, use a hair dryer to heat-set the paint after the paint has completely dried (at least 24 hours). This is also mentioned in https://canarystreetcrafts.com/how-to-turn-any-acrylic-paint-into-fabric-paint/. They suggest using an iron, but depending on where on the backpack you're painting, the fabric might not be flat enough for you to iron over. I would also personally be slightly worried about putting a backpack into a clothes dryer, in case it damages the bag - check the care tags on the backpack to see if it can be put in a dryer.

If your backpack is made of a synthetic material (like nylon) or another non-porous material like leather (my first backpack was leather), you can try alcohol inks. I have personally never tried using alcohol inks before, though, so I'm not sure how well it works on synthetic fabrics.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. My backpack has a leather material. I will try the things you have mentioned. Thanks again.!

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck :D

Comment: These paints (acrylic, fabric paint) **will not work on vinyl!!** which is what Naugahyde is. It is non porous material so there is nothing for the paint to hold on to. (don't approve so quickly!)   There are paints made specifically for vinyl, and other solvent based paints like oil based enamels may also work.  But the answer above is not likely to work... have you tried it yet? Let me know if I'm wrong. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the update - The original question didn't have the materials listed, so I hadn't crafted it specifically for Naugahyde leather - in which case, they should definitely look for paints designed for non-porous materials. I agree that **acrylic and fabric paints may chip/scrape off over time, even after drying and curing.** However, I've had great luck with using acrylic and fabric paints on other plastics (e.g. HDPE water bottle), but I've never specifically used it on faux leather. It'd be really helpful if the OP could post an update on what they tried and how well it worked!

Comment: I did some more research - It seems that they could either stencil & spray paint a design using upholstery spray paints, such as described here: https://www.homedit.com/paint-vinyl-upholstery/.
Also, this person tested 3 types of upholstery paint: https://www.apartmenttherapy.com/painting-vinyl-upholstery-215327).

Or...if WikiHow can be trusted... apparently acrylic paints might actually do the trick?
"Acrylic paint is perfect for using to paint faux leather. It is flexible, adheres well to faux leather and won’t crack with movement."
Source: https://www.wikihow.com/Paint-Faux-Leather

Answer (score 2):

Smudging can only mean either it hasn't dried properly or it's come into contact with something that softens it again. I reckon it's more likely to have been abraded. This could happen very easily if the paint is unsuitable for the fabric, but you're the one with the paint and backpack.

In particular some paints aren't suitable for synthetic fabrics, as they rely on soaking in to cotton a little. This may be the problem you've got. I've had some success stencilling with spray paint onto synthetic fabrics.

Answer (score 0):

I’d consider leather shoe dyes. Alternatively, embroidery.